# How to trigger a server side function by pressing a button in the client side gui using tkinter python

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

I want to get live video from my server side by clicking a button of the gui of client side. How it can be done? I am not getting any idea. Can anybody help me with the concept or by giving me some webpage address where I can get related code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not specified what You use for server for example if You use sockets, then the button press should just send the server some message that gets put into dictionary which then is related to a function and that is about it

Answer (score 0):

If you got a website or you have hosted it on your LAN:
you can pass the `command` argument
`btn.config(command=myfunc)`

Comment: the button is on the client side and I have to run the function of the server side

Comment: @AlmasrurKhan that passed function has to just send a message to server which will then read the message maybe use it as a key in a dictionary and get the correct function to execute

Comment: but the problem is I have to run several functions parallelly. So maybe using the mentioned way will cause a problem.

Comment: Hello, @Matiiss I can send the message to the server from the client now and the function also works. However, I am in need to send another message to the server for operating another function parallelly. Can you guide me on this? Thank you very much

Comment: @AlmasrurKhan send 2 messages with one function, send a message that runs two functions? If You want parallel, then You could use some list or sth and then run them all using some ThreadPool or sth, basically multiprocessing, there are tutorials on that, can only tell You abou threading which isn't exactly parallel.

Comment: @Matiss, maybe I was not able to explain my problem. The thing is I have some button on the client side gui. By pressing a button I am receiving video from server to client. now when my video is displaying I want to click another button in the client gui and want that the server will send one more thing (e.g. a message, a signal). But when the task of first button is running, the second task do not run after pressing the second button. Can you please help me?